# Xamarin Form - TaskCanceledException thrown on ScanFilesToFolderAsync

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp, win-universal-app

in my UWP application i am working on scan functionality. in this application user can scan the document through scanner by selecting flatbed or auto feeder.Now problem is when i am trying to scan it gives the en exception a Task was canceled.

please help..

thanks in advance. :)

have a great day... :)

```
private async void Btnscan_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        FolderPicker folderPicker = new FolderPicker();
        folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
        folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");

        StorageFolder folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
//set the destination folder name for scan images.


        DeviceInformationDisplay selectedScanner = CmbScannerList.SelectedItem as DeviceInformationDisplay; // here i got the selected scanner.

        // scanner id is := "\\\\?\\ROOT#IMAGE#0000#{6bdd1fc6-810f-11d0-bec7-08002be2092f}"

        ScanToFolder(selectedScanner.id, folder);


    }
```

function Scan To folder

```
 public async void ScanToFolder(string deviceId, StorageFolder folder)
    {
        try
        {
 cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();

            ImageScanner myScanner = await ImageScanner.FromIdAsync(deviceId);

            if (myScanner.IsScanSourceSupported(ImageScannerScanSource.Flatbed))
            {
                var result = await myScanner.ScanFilesToFolderAsync(ImageScannerScanSource.Flatbed, folder).AsTask(cancellationToken.Token); // through an exception(A Task Was Canceled):(
Utils.DisplayImageAndScanCompleteMessage(result.ScannedFiles, DisplayImage);

            }

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // here i got the exception.
        }

    }
```

Updated :

Now i am set the DeviceClass to ALL.

```
   private void StartWatcher()
    {
        resultCollection.Clear();
        DeviceWatcher deviceWatcher;

        deviceWatcher = DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher(DeviceClass.All); // set Image scanner to all. 
       deviceWatcherHelper.StartWatcher(deviceWatcher);
  }
```

After run the project in scanner list i got the all connected devices in which i got my scanner name This : when i am trying to pass this name it gives error in imagescanner System.Exception: 'Exception from HRESULT: 0x80210015' means device not found. 
Now i am chnage all to ImageScanner i got nothing in scanner list.

[image]

and in scanner HP application i got this name. and IT Scan Well :( in scanner list i don't got this name in my application. :( 
[image]

on my pc setting -> devices -> scanner and printers i got those name.

[image]

Comment: Where is the `cancellationToken` declared? Is it not actually canceled?

Comment: please check the code now its updated :)

Comment: And how is it initialized? It cannot be `null`

Comment: sorry i don't have any idea would please suggest some code :(

Comment: [link](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Scan-Runtime-API-Sample-5703b7a2/sourcecode?fileId=86722&pathId=1849918096)  i am referring this site. and i am remove the unwanted code.(scenarios)

Comment: Aren't you calling the `CancelScanning` somewhere? What happens if you remove the `AsTask` part completely?

Comment: it gives same error :( A task Was canceled .

Comment: Very weird, could you create a simple GitHub repo so I could try out your code directly?

Comment: git hub project sample:  [link](https://github.com/patilketan888/Scan-Image-in-UWP )

Comment: have you seen the code ? is it work ?

Comment: I have tested your project on my machine and it does seem to work as expected and I am getting no `TaskCanceledException`. Maybe there is some problem with your scanner drivers? Are you able to test on some other machine or with some other scanner?

Comment: Thank you for your valuable replay. :) i will check on another machine . i want to ask you the one question is their any TWAIN dll in nuGet package.which support scanning in uwp(xamarin Forms) ? or any third party library which is free :)  if yes please share the link . and again thank you :)

Comment: @Martin : still i am getting the TaskCanceledException. i am also check the scan image from scanner application which is provided by scanner company and it works as expected. which scanner do you use ?

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply, TWAIN.dll cannot be used directly in Xamarin.Forms and UWP, but you could use Desktop Extension (https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-2/) to launch full trust assembly and communicate with it.

Comment: I have a Samsung printer which has a scanner

Comment: @Martin : thank you for your reply. scanner is connected to your machine or network. because i am trying to access the scanner through network. please check this scenario on your machine. :) is their any access permission issue(Folder which we select for scan purpose) happen ?

Comment: @MartinZikmund Have you tried this scenario ?

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to tell, my scanner does not support network connection. Maybe someone else could check. I would expect a different exception in case of permission issue

Comment: @MartinZikmund : thank you for your reply. please check the updated question. :(  my scanner is connected in network. it detect and access by HP scan application. not my application.

Comment: @MartinZikmund  Finally it solved the issue. :) Thank you for your time and interest. :)  actually its driver issue. after driver reinstall it solve the issue :) Once again thank you :) Have a great day :)

Comment: Great! I have rewritten the solution as an answer, please consider accepting it so that the question is resolved. Happy coding!

Comment: @MartinZikmund sorry i am posting the question link do you have any idea about this in UWP [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56034495/11362349)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewriting the resolution of the problem as an answer. I tested the code on my machine where it behaved correctly and argued the problem is most likely a driver issue. This has been confirmed by the OP and reinstall of the driver helped make the scanning work again.