# Xamarin Form - How To store an image in PDF or JPEG Format in UWP

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

hello friends i am developing the DMS application in which user can scan the document or images through scanner and upload on server.

For scanning purpose i am refered this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.scanners.imagescanner.scanfilestofolderasync) it works perfectly..:)

Now problem is ImageScanner.ScanFilesToFolderAsync(ImageScannerScanSource, StorageFolder) this Method accepts the image format which is supported by scanner. my scanner only support the .BMP format but i want to store an image in PDF or JPEG Format in given folder name.

**Else** please suggest any free pdf package( dll). which accept multiple image format and convert to single pdf format and **PDFSharp** package support in uwp ?

thanks in advance :)

```
  ScannerSettings _ScannerSettings = new ScannerSettings();  

  ImageScanner scanner = await ImageScanner.FromIdAsync(_settings.DeviceId);

  scanner = _ScannerSettings.SetScannerSettings(scanner, _settings); // here i am trying to assigning the scanner settings with pdf or jpeg format.

 var operation =  scanner.ScanFilesToFolderAsync(AssignScannerType, folder); // it gives exception if i am passing the pdf or JPEG format in scanner settings because my scanner not support this format.
```

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/ststeiger/PdfSharpCore
is a port for .NET Core 1.6+
It doesn't use `System.Drawing.dll`.
It is based on PdfSharp 1.32 and has some missing and some half-working features.

https://github.com/ststeiger/PdfSharpNetStandard
Is for NetStandard 2.1+, and is based on PdfSharp 1.5.

Very few things are missing 
(https://github.com/ststeiger/PdfSharpNetStandard/tree/master/PdfSharp_Removed 
https://github.com/ststeiger/PdfSharpNetStandard/tree/master/MigraDoc_Rendering_Removed).
PdfSharpNetStandard should work work just like PdfSharp.

`PdfSharpCore` has changed `PdfSharp` to be based on the .NET-Core High-Performance implementations.
It should have a better/higher performance - in theory.

Comment: thank you for your valuable reply. i have installed the PDFSHARPCORE. but problem is i got **Access Denied Exception** on this line XImage img = XImage.FromFile(path);

Comment: problem solved :) i am start storing scaned images to ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync() folder and access denied problem solved. :) and all images converted successfully to single pdf Thnaks you :) for pdf code refered this [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1023435/Converting-Multiple-Image-Files-to-PDF)  link :)

Comment: Please mark it as answer if it helped you :-) thanks

Comment: 1.when i am install the PdfSharpCore in my uwp project in debug mode it works perfectly. **But** when i am trying to create a package in Release mode package will not be created through errors. 2. when i am installed the PdfSharpNetStandard from nuget package it Gives error like system.Drawing is not supported for this platform.  :( Which Dll support in uwp ??

Comment: Any idea how to store an image in pdf or jpeg format in uwp windows application. :(